# Creating a tuple without using tuple function

Tags: python, tuples

I have to create a list of tuples without using the tuple() function. The input is a list of lists where each list contains a profile ID and the calendar date on which the user went of a date. The output is a list of tuples showing the profile ID and the number of dates the user went on.

The final output should be a list of tuples, but my code outputs each element individually.
Below is the code I wrote to try to convert the list elements to tuples.

```py
for stuff in datingTrack:
        for smallerStuff in stuff:
            tuplesList = (smallerStuff)
            datingTrack2.append(tuplesList)
```

```
input: [["B111", "10/2/2022"], ["B222", "9/25/2022"], ["B333", "8/1/2022"], ["B222", "9/2/2022"]]

my output: ['B111', 1, 'B222', 2, 'B333', 1]

Expected output: [('B111', 1,) ('B222', 2), ('B333', 1)]
```

Comment: `tuplesList = (smallerStuff)` is *exactly equivalent* to `tuplesList = smallerStuff`, note, it isn't the *parentheses* that make the tuple, it is the commas! (except for the special case of an empty tuple, which is `()`)

Comment: BTW, `tuple` is not a function, but a [class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-tuple) that, as with many classes from the Standard Library, is normally used _as a function_ just because there's a simple synaxis to create tuples without explicitly calling it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EDIT: This does not answer the question. Please refer to the answers above

---

If you're forced to not use the tuple construtor, this will do it

```py
my_input = [["B111", "10/2/2022"], ["B222", "9/25/2022"], ["B333", "8/1/2022"], ["B222", "9/2/2022"]]

my_output = [(*item,) for item in my_input]
# [('B111', '10/2/2022'), ('B222', '9/25/2022'), ('B333', '8/1/2022'), ('B222', '9/2/2022')]
```

Comment: But this doesn't show the number of occurrences of each ID...

Comment: If this is the answer then the question is the wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the expected output with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

lst = [
    ["B111", "10/2/2022"],
    ["B222", "9/25/2022"],
    ["B333", "8/1/2022"],
    ["B222", "9/2/2022"],
]

c = Counter(v for v, _ in lst)
print(list(c.items()))
```

Prints:

```py
[('B111', 1), ('B222', 2), ('B333', 1)]
```

---

EDIT: Solution without `Counter`:

```
lst = [
    ["B111", "10/2/2022"],
    ["B222", "9/25/2022"],
    ["B333", "8/1/2022"],
    ["B222", "9/2/2022"],
]

out = {}
for v, _ in lst:
    out[v] = out.get(v, 0) + 1

out = list(out.items())
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[('B111', 1), ('B222', 2), ('B333', 1)]
```

Comment: if they can't use `tuple` then why would they b e able to use `collections.Counter`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, OP wanted solution without using `tuple()`, he/she got it ;) But I get your point...

Comment: Ya I can't use counter either :,( it has to be done using a loop somehow

Answer (score 0):

This one almost does what you want:

```
datingTrack = [["B111", "10/2/2022"], ["B222", "9/25/2022"], ["B333", "8/1/2022"], ["B222", "9/2/2022"]]

dt2 = [(ID,len ([i for [i,j] in datingTrack if i==ID])) for (ID,date) in datingTrack]
```

Almost, because there will be multiple identical entries.
But that can be solved with:

```
dt2 = list(set(dt2))
```